# Swift: I want to sort the series I have by the number of 'a' in the names' surnames. The name and surname in the series are in the same index

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, sorting, generics

[app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr0QS.png)
I can check the number of "a" in this array I have, but I could not find how I should sort it.

- write a String extension function that will help you count the number of occurrences of a character in a string.
- rite a function that will receive an array of strings and a character. This function will be responsible for sorting members in the array with respect to following rules:
  i. By using the extension function you wrote, find the most occurences of the character for each string in the array and sort in descending order.
  ii. If two or more strings contain the same amount for the character, sort these according to their length.
  iii. If two or more strings contain the same amount for the character and have the same length, sort these in alphabetical order.

**Example:**

let array = ["xxx baba", "yyy bababa"," zzz bbaba","ggg sjsj"]

return = ["yyy bababa", " zzz bbaba", "xxx baba", "ggg sjsj"]

- When the Sort button is tapped, please call this function for the last names of the members, for the character “a” and update the UI with respect to the sorted list.

Comment: No, it's not homework, I guess that's perceived because I simplified the question. I want to sort my tableview by typing a String Extension

Comment: I'm trying to write a string extension to sort the names in my TableView, but after splitting the arrays and sorting the last names, I can't convert the array back to its original form and put it in the tableview.

Comment: "I'm trying to write a string extension to sort the names in my TableView, but after splitting the arrays and sorting the last names, I can't convert the array back to its original form and put it in the tableview.". What's your sort code? Did you succeed in sorting your array? Is your issue about sorting your arrays BY a property (name)? Show your current code.

Comment: Why not use a struct instead of keeping the full names in a string? If not please share your attempt to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your first question

```
    func FindingNoofCh( array : [String]) {
        var SearchHash : Dictionary<Character , Int> = [:]

        for string in array {
            for  (index , ch) in string.enumerated() {
                if ch.isWhitespace {
                    continue
                }
                let alreadyExit : Bool = SearchHash[ch] != nil

                if alreadyExit {
                    SearchHash[ch]! += 1
                    print("no of times \(ch) is \(SearchHash[ch]!) times")
                }else {
                    SearchHash[ch] = 1
                    print("no of times \(ch) is \(SearchHash[ch]!) times")
            }
            
            }
            SearchHash = [:]

        }
        
}
```

```
for second function:
    func SortingMembers(array : [String] , ch : Character) -> [String] {
        
        var SearchHash : Dictionary<Character , Int> = [:]
        var history : [Dictionary<Character , Int>] = [[:]]
        
        let array = array
        var returningarray : [Dictionary<String , Int>] = [[:]]
        var x : Int = 0
        
        for string in array {
            for  (_ , ch) in string.enumerated() {
                if ch.isWhitespace {
                    continue
                }
                let alreadyExit : Bool = SearchHash[ch] != nil
                
                if alreadyExit {
                    SearchHash[ch]! += 1
                }else {
                    SearchHash[ch] = 1
                }
                
            }
            history.append(SearchHash)
            SearchHash = [:]
            
            
        }
        history.removeFirst()
        print(history)
        returningarray.removeFirst()
        for (index  , eachhistory) in history.enumerated() {
            if let amount = eachhistory[ch]  {
                
                print(amount)
                if amount > x {
                    x  = amount
                    returningarray.insert([array[index] : amount], at: 0)
                    continue
                }
                if amount == x && array[index-1].count != array[index].count {
                    if  array[index-1].count < array[index].count{
                        returningarray.insert([array[index] : amount], at: index-1)
                    }else {
                        returningarray.append([array[index] : amount])
                    }
                    
                    
                }else if amount == x && array[index-1].count == array[index].count {
                    if array[index] > array[index - 1] {
                        returningarray.insert([array[index] : 0], at: index-1)
                    }else {
                        returningarray.append([array[index] : 0])
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
            returningarray.insert([array[index] : 0], at: returningarray.endIndex)
        }
        var finalarray = [String]()
        for array in returningarray {
            for (data,_) in array {
                finalarray.append(data)
            }
        }
        print(finalarray)
        return finalarray
        
    }
```

you can optimize yourself as its by brute force.
give it a vote and let me know :)

Comment: I do not know what to say. It has been an amazing solution indeed, I hope I can be like you in the future.